# Get all duplicate keys from a POST request with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I decided to give typescript a try and make a small authentication API with express. What I wanted to do now is, make the `username` and `email` unique, so my mongoose schema looks as follows:

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Username is required!'],
    unique: true,
    min: 6,
    max: 255,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Email is required!'],
    unique: true,
    min: 6,
    max: 255,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Password is required!'],
    min: 6,
    max: 1024,
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now(),
  },
});

export const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

My controller is also very simple:

```
export async function registerUser(
  req: express.Request,
  res: express.Response,
): Promise<express.Response> {
  const user = new User({
    username: req.body.username,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
  });
  const error = user.validateSync();
  if (error) {
    return res.status(400).json(error);
  }
  await user.save(function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).send(err);
    }
    return res.status(200).send({ success: true, message: 'User created!' });
  });
}
```

This all works as expected, however, if I do a POST request, where both the email and username already exist in the database, I do not get a response with both of them in the body. For example if I make a POST request with:

```
{
    "username": "username2",
    "email": "emailblabla2",
    "password": "password1234"
}
```

where `username2` and `emailblabla2` have already been used, I will first get:

```
{
    "driver": true,
    "name": "MongoError",
    "index": 0,
    "code": 11000,
    "keyPattern": {
        "username": 1
    },
    "keyValue": {
        "username": "username2"
    }
}
```

as a response and at the second attempt I will get the same but for the email.

Is it possible to get both at the same time? Should I even be using mongoose to validate my data? I see a lot of people recommending joi, however, I thought if mongoose is already capable of doing that, why use an additional library for it.

Comment: that validateSync call does not smell good to me

Comment: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#the-unique-option-is-not-a-validator looks like you are getting the first duplicate key error thrown because of your mongo index. worth trying to write your own custom validator

Comment: Why? It's to call the mongoose validators (which sadly [do not include the duplicates](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#the-unique-option-is-not-a-validator) hence the additional function with err)

Comment: That's just a guess honestly. How would validation against your db work without an IO ? Given the choice between a synchronous call and an asynchronous one I would go for async. but maybe I'm wrong in this context